# Genymotion 3.0 trial version showing Black Screen on Windows 10

Tags: android, genymotion

My Genymotion is showing black screen i have try all the methode of configuration by configuring correctly my virtual box adapter so i don't know what's wrong again.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you add the content of genymotion.log and the log file for your device?

Comment: Make sure that firewall or any other third party software not blocks your genymotion

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and in my case the problem was the graphics card.

Genymotion requires reasonably recent graphic cards. In my case, my laptop graphic card was running with the generic graphics drives by MS. I updated the graphics driver in Windows Control Panel, and right after that the emulator worked.

Here is the official support page that lists a few of the possible causes and remedies for black screen:

https://www.genymotion.com/faq/#virtual-device-window-empty

Answer (score 0):

You need to **check** 4 different things:

1. proxy connections to be off( *Gennymotion/setting/Network*)

[image]

2. SDK be set( *Gennymotion/ABD/SDK*)
   [image]
3. Graphic card driver be successfully installed
   [image]
4. Virtual box installed and working correctly
   [image]

> Try again please. hope you will fix it easily.